# Is it harmful to use a prong collar?

Tags: dogs, safety, collar

I asked this question [Can check (choke) chains still be used to successfully train dogs?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/783/whats-the-deal-with-using-check-chains-these-days) and wanted to address specifically the use of a prong collar.

[image: prong collar]

(image courtesy of [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:ProngCollar_wb.jpg))

Is it harmful to  use a prong collar and if so, why?

Comment: see this, similar and valid http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/749/do-invisible-fences-pose-long-term-health-risks-to-dogs

Comment: Some research shows a variety of published answers to this question. Answers would do well to to choose solid supporting references

Comment: @JamesJenkins totally agree, we need good answers for all the posts

Comment: This will be particularly difficult as there are two distinct and non-compatible points of view.

Answer (score 3):

First we could say that yes, this is clearly harmful, and that's the whole point of it !

Then we should ask ourselves "do I want to harm my dog" ? This depends on your own point of view.

But then, more importantly: do we need to harm a dog to train it ?

Many methods that were used in the past, and that are still used in many places are based on outdated concepts and training methods: strongly jerking the leash, using choke collars, etc.

Nowadays most successful trainers use so-called "positive reinforcement methods": from dolphins, chickens, horses, humans (google "tag teaching"), to dogs. These methods are based on real and up-to-date scientific results (applied psychology meeting ethology) and are constantly evolving and being refined. As an introduction to this I suggest to read [this](http://dogmantics.com/progressive-reinforcement-training-manifesto/english-manifesto/).

Answering the question "do we need to use chain collars to be successful" also avoids the endless debate "yes it hurts - no, it's not too bad, etc.". People arguing to use these tools are constantly getting closer to abusing their pets.